# CSS for mega menu in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

See http://jsfiddle.net/jN5G4/1/

How do I the "*5 Columns*" menu drop down to align like the other drop downs?

I removed the `<a href...> </a>` tags from the *5 Columns* list item and now the drop down menu that drops down from under that item drops down over the main menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because plain body text does not register as a block-level element and your dropdown is basically aligning itself from the top portion of your text. To fix is simply add your plain text inside a block-level element like a `p` tag or enclose it inside a `span` tag, just make sure to display it as a block, like so:

**CSS**

```
#menu li span {
  display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li>
   <span>5 Columns</span>
....
```